# How do I rar a file into several parts in Linux?

Tags: linux, compression, rar

I want to make a rar file(not tar or gzip) with several parts in linux shell, how is it possible ?

for example my file is : m.avi - 500mb

I want this :

```
m.part1.rar 250mb
m.part2.rar 250mb
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ah I misunderstood, for parting rar files you have to do the following. First make sure you have rar installed. Then use the following command:

```
rar a -v250000k /path/m.splitted.rar /path/m.avi
```

**a** for append, **-v** for the size in kilobytes.
This would create /path/m.splitted.part001.rar, /path/m.splitted.part002.rar, etc.

If you want the old naming scheme (m.splitted.rar as the first file, then m.splitted.r01, m.splitted.r02, etc.) you should use **-vn** instead of **-v**.
See /usr/share/doc/rar/rar.txt for more information.

Comment: You can write volume size as Megabyte with *M*. I mean using `rar -a -v250M ...`

Comment: This worked for me `rar a -m5 -v5M -R myarchive.rar /home/`

Comment: `rar a -v3G outout.rar movie.mkv` works great for 3GB files.

Comment: Lol this takes ages.

Comment: there is a bit issue, rar name and file should be the same